# React Native Redux Connect won't open android.js or ios.js extension

Tags: javascript, redux, react-native, react-native-ios

I was trying to have my connectors open up a component in a clean and easily readable way for Android & iOS platforms. To me this is using the component.android.js and component.ios.js extensions for things that are majorly different like tabs over slide-in drawer, etc.

Yes, I am aware of the Platform object I can create conditions on, however I really want to make this clean from an ES6 modules stand point and I don't think conditional import statements are clean or even possible.

```js
'use strict'

import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import DashboardView from './DashboardView';


/* Mapping */

const mapStateToProps = state => {
 return {
  display: state.app.deviceInformation,
 }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, props) => {
 return {}
}
 
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(DashboardView);
```

Again, what I want here is to have DashboardView automatically know that if in Android it should open DashboardView.android.js and on iOS obviously DashboardView.ios.js

That would be much cleaner to handle separate UI components... to me anyway.

Comment: The code sample you posted should work just fine. Can you post the file structure of the directory where your component lives, as well as the `export` statements from each of the components?

Comment: All of my components are being correctly exported via `export default class DashboardView extends Component`

Answer (score 0):

I have just discovered the correct answer by accident. Figured it's worth documenting here.

I changed the `DashboardView.android.js` & `DashboardView.ios.js` file names to instead be `index.android.js` & `index.ios.js`

Works like a charm now, all is well.